# Restructuring a large data matrix

Tags: r, list, matrix, data-structures

I have a matrix of 187,727 observations of 27 variables.

Each row consists of a species name and the trait measurements associated with that name. There are uneven observations for each species.

I'd like to make reviewing the matrix somewhat easier. My initial thought was to create a for loop which identified the number of unique species names, then identify how many entries there are for that species, then shift over the data to a list of which information was grouped under each species name. I could then call each set of species information to review separately.

Unfortunately, I've come to a roadblock in my understanding of how to do this. Here is how far I managed to get:

```
traits <- list()

for(i in 1:length(unique(data.traits$AccSpeciesName))){

    name <- data.traits$AccSpeciesName[i]

      for(j in 1:sum(data.traits$AccSpeciesName %in% data.traits$AccSpeciesName[name])){

          traits[i,j] <- data.traits[j,]

     }
}
```

Comment: Learn to use `split`.

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data?  The output from `dput(head(data.traits))` for example would help tremendously.

Comment: Also, show the answer you want for that small data set.

Comment: What do you mean by uneven observations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see how user `42` is suggesting you solve this, try looking at `?split` which divides up data frames or matrices based on a grouping factor `f` that you provide. Here's a small example:

```
data(iris)
mylist = split(x = iris, f = iris$Species)
lapply(mylist, summary)
```

More explicit code might look like this:

```
data(iris)

# using `split` ----
mylist = split(iris, iris$Species)

# return the rows of the data frame where the Species column is equal ----
# to each of the unique values that the column takes ---------------------
mylist2 = lapply(levels(iris$Species), function(x) iris[iris$Species == x,])
names(mylist2) = levels(iris$Species) # so that all.equal will return TRUE

# compare the two ways --------
all.equal(mylist, mylist2) # TRUE
```